# Why is my PayPal IPN script failing?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm developing a lightweight e-commerce solution that uses *PayPal* as the payment gateway. However, my IPN callback is constantly returning an `INVALID` response. I even tried using the sample PHP script provided by *PayPal*:

```
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp) {
  // HTTP ERROR
}
else {
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
      // check the payment_status is Completed
      // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
      // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
      // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
      // process payment
    }
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
      // log for manual investigation
    }
  }
  fclose ($fp);
}
```

But as I say, I keep getting an `INVALID` response. This is in fact the response I get using a PHP class that writes the response to a log file:

```
[2011-06-02 19:18:49] - FAIL: IPN Validation Failed.
IPN POST data from PayPal:
test_ipn=1,
payment_type=instant,
payment_date=11:07:43 Jun 02, 2011 PDT,
payment_status=Completed,
payer_status=verified,
first_name=John,
last_name=Smith,
payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com,
payer_id=TESTBUYERID01,
business=seller@paypalsandbox.com,
receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com,
receiver_id=TESTSELLERID1,
residence_country=US,
item_name1=something,
item_number1=AK-1234,
quantity1=1,
tax=2.02,
mc_currency=USD,
mc_fee=0.44,
mc_gross=15.34,
mc_gross_1=12.34,
mc_handling=2.06,
mc_handling1=1.67,
mc_shipping=3.02,
mc_shipping1=1.02,
txn_type=cart,
txn_id=4362187,
notify_version=2.4,
custom=xyz123,
invoice=abc1234,
charset=windows-1252,
verify_sign=AjbdIvvDAW2fh1O9jAbEym4myX.WAV7-jCEiEWMqoSkewvM6L3Co6oUQ
```

This is from the official *PayPal* IPN test tool. So something between *PayPal*'s sample code and test tool is causing my script to fail. Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is encoding of your html/php page ? (charset=windows-1252) ?

Comment: No. It's UTF-8 I believe... `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` (HTML 5).

Comment: So why you use charset windows-1252 ;)
I have same problem yesterday

Comment: Configure on your paypal account !
Sandbox too !

Comment: And how would one change this setting? Which section in my *PayPal* account is it under?

Comment: My paypal are in french so sorry for traduction

Preferencs=>more options => preference sell => Encode language => more options

http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide/ProfileAndTools.html

Comment: Nope. Still getting an `INVALID` response.

Comment: business=seller@paypalsandbox.com,
receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com

Are valide ?

Comment: It comes from the IPN test tool so I would presume so?

Comment: you etablishe connection with real server paypal not sandbox<br>
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);<br>
I think it's<br>
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);<br>

Comment: \o/
Just don't forget to create function for check if txn_id are not already use :)