# $response and $status in paypal's ipn have no values?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

What is the purpose of the following two lines in the ipn.php example code from paypal developers site?

```
$response = curl_exec($request);
$status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

When I test `$response` and `$status`, `@status` gives me the value `0` and `$response` has no value.

Here is all the code I have before the two lines above at executed:

```
<?php

    // Does this code actually run?
    error_log("yes");

    // Capture the post
    $ipn_post_data = $_POST;

    // Choose url
    if(array_key_exists('test_ipn', $ipn_post_data) && 1 === (int) $ipn_post_data['test_ipn'])
        $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    else
        $url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

    // Set up request to PayPal
    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($request, array
    (
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('cmd' => '_notify-validate') + $ipn_post_data),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
    ));

    // Execute request and get response and status code
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    $status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

I can see a `yes` in the apache error logs, so I know this file gets executed when paypal returns ipn data back to my test server.

However, when I check the `$payment_status` returned from paypal, it always works, i.e. when then payment has worked properly, `$payment_status` is `Complete`, when it's pending, `$payment_status` paypal return to my server is `Pending` and so on.  So the code works, I just don't understand why the `$response` and `$status` are being used as they are blank.

Comment: I don't see the $payment_status variable in your code... that's the part that is confusing me.  Also, have you tried putting logging after the curl_exec() too - to make sure that that is actually running?

Comment: The payment_status part of the code works, which is why I didn't include it.  It comes shortly after the snippet I have shown above.

Comment: is $url setted correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**can you pleas check this :**

If you connect with the server, then you can get a return code from it, otherwise it will fail and you get a 0. So if you try to connect to "www.google.com/lksdfk" you will get a return code of 400, if you go directly to google.com, you will get 302 (and then 200 if you forward to the next page... well I do because it forwards to google.com.br, so you might not get that), and if you go to "googlecom" you will get a 0 (host no found), so with the last one, there is nobody to send a code back.

**Tested using the code below.**

```
<?php

$html_brand = "www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $html_brand,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $httpCode != 200 ){
    echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
        .curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($response)."</pre>";
}

curl_close($ch);
```

**OR Second Reason :**

Realized that I was having SSL issues. Simply set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false. Works.

**OR Third Reason :**

**CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT** - The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.

**CURLOPT_TIMEOUT** - The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

**also don't forget to enlarge time execution of php script self:**

```
set_time_limit(0);// to infinity for example
```

Answer (score 0):

`curl_exec()`: If you connect with the server, then you can get a return code from it, otherwise it will fail and you get a 0.

Check if URL is correct and check your encoding too: [Why is my PayPal IPN script failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218606/why-is-my-paypal-ipn-script-failing?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using a library over re-inventing the wheel. I personally use https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

Comment: paypal ipn api is so simple any library is probably more complicated